# How can i pass data between classes python

Tags: python

I have two classes one for the `MainWindow` and other for a `QDiaalog`:

```
class Menu(QMainWindow):
  logginuser= None
  def __init__(self,):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
```

The class `Entrega` that belongs to `QDialog` is called through a button that connects to this function:

```
def switch_windows(self):

    self.entrega2 = Entrega(self.tableLinhaNova)
```

And the class `Entrega`:

```
class Entrega(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, source_table_widget,parent=Menu):

    QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

But in the class `Entrega` there is information that I want to pass to the Menu class, which is this:

```
self.projeto=self.ui.comboBoxProjeto.currentIndex()
    self.idproj = self.ui.comboBoxProjeto.itemData(self.projeto)
```

`self.idproj` is an Id, it can be `1`,`2`,`3` etc...

How can I pass `self.idproj` to `Menu` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom signal for the QDialog.

```
class Entrega(QDialog):
    id_changed: pyqtSignal() = pyqtSignal(int) # Add this signal

    def __init__(self, source_table_widget, parent=Menu):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

When your id changed, you have to emit that signal with the id that you have:

```
self.projeto = self.ui.comboBoxProjeto.currentIndex()
self.idproj = self.ui.comboBoxProjeto.itemData(self.projeto)
self.id_changed.emit(self.idproj) # Emit signal here.
```

Now, when the signal emitted, you have to connect to it to get the emitted id:

```
def switch_windows(self):
    self.entrega2 = Entrega(self.tableLinhaNova)
    self.entrega2.ic_changed.connect(lambda id: self.do_something_with_id(id)) #Get id here.
```

I have not tested the code yet. But this might helps to have the flow of how you get the id. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I´m having a problem whit your solution, my program is in pyside6 so i use the signal from pyside6, but nothing happens , i dont know if the signal is no sending the id, or i must did something wrong

Comment: I hope you can find the solution that will working with pyside, since the code above is written for pyqt5.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several ways of exchanging data between classes.

Here is a boiler plate of the simplest example (using the constructor):

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A("Hello")
b = B(a)

print(b.a.data)  # Output: Hello
```

You can also do this by:

1. using a method
2. using a property